# Parse load data in array swift

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform

Im trying to load Parse data and set in a array as result, i check a few questions but many codes are outdate so I'm stuck, how i can set the query in a array? heres the code:

```
var array [String] = []

func loadData() {

    var query = PFQuery(className: "ParseClass")

    query.orderByAscending("column")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            self.array.append( objects! )// error here

        } else {

            println( error?.userInfo )
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing the objects yet?

Comment: i can't its give a error "cannot invoke 'append' with a argument list of type ([AnyObject])"

Comment: Did you follow what the Parse blog did? It seems like you set where PFObject should be in your block function to AnyObject. [link](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/building-apps-with-parse-and-swift/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is a little wrong here, this is how I would come around to doing it.

```
var array: [String] = [String]()
var query = PFQuery(className: "ParseClass")

func loadData() {

    query.orderByAscending("column")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{ (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    for object in objects {
                           self.array.append(object.objectForKey("column") as! String)
                    }
}
```

Another problem that I spotted is that I think you trying to save an array of objects and not an array of an attribute of the class. My method above just stores the objects attribute called `column` in an array. If you want to store the PFObjects in an array then you are going to have to change the `array` variable you created to type PFObject like this : `var array: [PFObject] = [PFObject]()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this code:

```
var array = NSMutableArray()   //Change your array type to NSMutableArray

func loadData1() {

    var query = PFQuery(className: "ParseClass")

    query.orderByAscending("column")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            //loop your objects array
            for object in objects{

                let yourObject = object as! PFObject
                //add your element into array
                self.array.addObject(yourObject)
            }

            let tempArr :NSArray = self.array.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
            self.array = NSMutableArray(array: tempArr)

        } else {

            println( error?.userInfo )
        }
    }

}
```